# With jQuery, I need to create a delimited string based on input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have the following:

```
<div id="mypanel">
  <input id="hiddeninput"></input>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

On blur of any of those textboxes, I need to populate the hidden textbox with the values from each, separated by a "|" or a safer character if you have any suggestions. Whatever that delimiter character is I'll have to remove it on keyup while the user enters text.

So the hidden textbox would be populated with:

some text|some more text, and... etc.|and some more

I've done something similar with comma as an array:

```
 dataArray.push($(this).val().split(',')[0]);
```

Comment: Not clear... what is your question?

Comment: Each time a blur event is triggered on any of the visible text boxes, I need the value of the hidden text box to be a PIPE delimited string of the 3 text box values. Or I need to search through them, and if the value is not empty, populate the hidden field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: Simpler with $.map()**

```
$(".textbox input").blur(function() {
    var array = $(".textbox input").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join('|'); // replace '|' with any separator
    $("#hiddeninput").val(array);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cojax/3)**

**Older:**

```
var $hiddenInput = $("#hiddeninput");

$(".textbox input").blur(function() {
  var array = [];
  $(".textbox input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val()!="")  // ignore this if you don't want to check null
    {
      array.push($(this).val());
    }  
  });
  $hiddenInput.val(array.join("|"));
});
```

Remove the if condition, if you don't want to check for empty.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/buwuh/1)**

Comment: fewer lines using `$.map()`

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I had to use the Older one. The one with map has strange behavior on the delimiter like when you remove text from one, add it back in, etc. Puts double pipes.